# Is there any way to increase the default wait in Frameworkium, for @Visible-annotated fields

Tags: java, frameworkium

I have a *very* slow CI agent which runs a bunch of Frameworkium tests. These tests use Frameworkium's `@Visible` annotation (among others), which causes an implicit wait for the element to be visible on the page.

Unfortunately, at times the tests run so slowly that the page hasn't loaded after the default 10 second timeout. Is there any way I can increase that?

I know that I can change the default implicit wait in Selnium, but from digging through the Frameworkium code it looks like it's hardcoded in the `UITestLifecycle` class, and so I can't change it - am I wrong?

Comment: Hi, I just edited the tags on this question because it was somehow marked as [tag:untagged] which is a [special tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372558/no-question-should-be-untagged) that is assigned when the original tags are somehow deleted, leaving the question in an invalid state without any tags. I took my best guess as to the correct tags, but you might want to [edit] the question and fix them.  I ask because there's currently an effort to sort these out, see [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399176).

Comment: @dbc thanks, they seem like a reasonable set of tags, can't think of anything else I'd have used originally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Visible` uses the wait defined on the `Page`.

Therefore, if you'd like to change it you have to change the way the page is constructed. There are two options for this:

1. If you are using the `PageFactory` you can use `PageFactory.newInstance(MyPage.class, Duration.of(15, SECONDS))` or
2. `new MyPage().get(Duration.ofSeconds(20))`

If you need to change this per environment you might want to write your own `PageFactory` with a runtime configurable default duration (or, if this is a popular request, we might look to allow this default to be parametrised).